# Is pyinstaller's '--onefile' command working?

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

I had converted my python file using pyinstaller, using '--onefile' method. Hovewer, it still created folders.

Also, the .exe can run without these folders (I tried this by deleting other folders). So, is this exe file onefile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `exe` file that was created **is** a `onefile`. Let us look at the following command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile myscript.py
```

The [`pyinstaller`](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html) documentation says the following:

> PyInstaller analyzes myscript.py and:
>
> - Writes myscript.spec in the same folder as the script.
> - Creates a folder build in the same folder as the script if it does not exist.
> - Writes some log files and working files in the build folder.
> - Creates a folder dist in the same folder as the script if it does not exist.
> - Writes the myscript executable folder in the dist folder.
>
> In the dist folder you find the bundled app you distribute to your
> users.

The [`--onefile`](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html#cmdoption-F) optional option creates a one-file bundled executable. The presence of the `dist` and `build` folders are a byproduct of the pyinstaller command.